# Catch IO Exception Not executed

Tags: java, netbeans

The code inside the catch block is not executed when an exception is thrown. I am not sure if the exception is being thrown where i think it is. Any thoughts?
This is the output:

Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException

```
receivedPicBase64 = pic1builder.toString();

try {
    byte[] picbytearray = Base64.decode(receivedPicBase64);
    BufferedImage imag = ImageIO.read(newByteArrayInputStream(picbytearray));
    ImageIO.write(imag, imgType, new File(dirName,fileName));    
    }    
catch (IOException ex) {
    showError("Picture not fully received");
    System.out.println("Inside Catch Block");  
    }
finally{
    receivedPicBase64 = "";
    pic1builder.delete(0, pic1builder.length());
    System.out.println("End of Finally Block");

    }
```

Comment: Check the exception stack trace. It literally tells you the line which it is thrown from.

Comment: The exception is being thrown in the second last line of the try statement. I know this because i am purposely creating errors. my problem is that the catch is not executing when those errors occur.

Comment: Furthermore, whenever you catch an exception, you always want to put the stack trace somewhere. Right now your catch block just eats it. That doesn't help you out at all, because then you don't know anything about the error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

update your code likewise,

```
try {
     ...   
   }    
catch (IOException ex) {
    ...
    }
catch (NullPointerException ex) {
    showError("NullPointerException catch");
    System.out.println("Inside NullPointerException-Catch Block");  
    }
finally{
    ....
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

`NullPointerException` is NOT an `IOException`.

Answer (score 1):

Your catch will only catch IOException. If you want to catch all exceptions, use

```
catch (Exception ex) {
    showError("Picture not fully received");
    System.out.println("Inside Catch Block");  
}
```

Comment: Almost certainly not what OP wants, however.